# I am getting a key error when trying to print from my dictionary

Tags: keyerror

I am getting a Key error "name" when i run the following code. I believe the name in my dictionary to be defined so i am unsure what the source of the error is.

'''
The task is broken down into three sections.

- Section 1 - User Input
- Section 2 - loop through the grocery list
- Section 3 - provide output to the console
  '''

## Task: Create the empty data structure

```
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = []
```

## Variable used to check if the while loop condition is met

`stop = False`

while not stop :

#Accept input of the name of the grocery item purchased.

`name = input("item Name:\n")`

#Accept input of the quantity of the grocery item purchased.

`quantity = input("quantity purchased:\n")`

#Accept input of the cost of the grocery item input (this is a per-item cost).

`cost = input("price per item:\n")`

#Using the update function to create a dictionary entry which contains the name, number and price entered by the user.

`grocery_item = {'item_name':(name), 'quantity':int(quantity), 'cost':float(cost)}`

#Add the grocery_item to the grocery_history list using the append function

`grocery_history.append(grocery_item)`

#Accept input from the user asking if they have finished entering grocery items.

```
  response = input("Would you like to enter another item?\n Type 'c' to continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
  if response == 'q':
    stop = True
```

## Define variable to hold grand total called 'grand_total'

`grand_total = 0`

## Define a 'for' loop.

`for item in grocery_history:`

#Calculate the total cost for the grocery_item.

`item_total = item['quantity'] * item['cost']`

#Add the item_total to the grand_total

`grand_total += item_total`

#Output the information for the grocery item to match this example:
  #2 apple  @   $1.49   ea  $2.98

```
print("{} {} @ ${} ea {}" .format(item['quantity'], item['name'], item['cost'], item_total))
```

#Set the item_total equal to 0

`item_total = 0`

## Print the grand total

`print ("Grand Total: $"(grand_total))`

```
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
```

Comment: It would be good to tag your post with the language it is written on. So for example, if this is written in python, then tag it python as well as keyerror. That way people that are looking at python posts will see your post as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` should be `item_name`, because this line:

`grocery_item = {'item_name':(name), 'quantity':int(quantity), 'cost':float(cost)}`

You assigned the input `name` to `item_name`.

Therefore, this line:

`print("{} {} @ ${} ea {}" .format(item['quantity'], item['name'], item['cost'], item_total))`

should replace by :

`print("{} {} @ ${} ea {}" .format(item['quantity'], item['item_name'], item['cost'], item_total))`